# bring the activity front of all the running application

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I have developed an alert reminder type application, so when alarm is called my broadcast receiver call one activity and fire one notification and also start one service, it working good,

But when I working in other application some time the my service  and notification is fired but activity is not open. it happen sometime not all.

So, how can I give the priority to my activity so it can open always if we working on other application, just like in call receiver screen.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/29769255/769265

Answer (score 1):

I think you cannot bring your app to top when other other apps are in front. The call receiver screen is system window which has special privileges. You cannot have the same for your app.

As a alternative you can fire a notification to status bar.

Comment: Actually, you can bring your app to the front. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/29769255/769265